# How do I disable nodes in Node-Red through CLI?

Tags: node-red

I need to programmatically disable a node in Node Red.

I have serial in and serial out nodes that communicate with arduinos and block the ability to upload new code. I know the ids of the nodes I would like to disable. This is the command I have been using to disable them:

```
node-red admin disable e5fd8ce75fd15002
400: Module not found
```

I am not sure how to use the disable command using the Node-Red CLI. I do not have any authorization set up. What is the correct command to disable specific nodes and deploy the new flow?

```
1 Jun 17:33:42 - [info] Node-RED version: v3.0.2
1 Jun 17:33:42 - [info] Node.js  version: v16.17.1
1 Jun 17:33:42 - [info] Windows_NT 10.0.19045 x64 LE
```

Here is a simple flow that I would like to be able to disable the serial nodes through the CLI:

```
[
    {
        "id": "41d9078ecff8c4b2",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Flow 3",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": "",
        "env": []
    },
    {
        "id": "a045b9b32cc25618",
        "type": "ui_button",
        "z": "41d9078ecff8c4b2",
        "name": "",
        "group": "fb4c245.8e22cd8",
        "order": 6,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "passthru": false,
        "label": "Send Input",
        "tooltip": "",
        "color": "",
        "bgcolor": "",
        "className": "",
        "icon": "",
        "payload": "{\"action\":\"do_stuff\"}",
        "payloadType": "json",
        "topic": "topic",
        "topicType": "msg",
        "x": 250,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": [
            [
                "52445f67209363f3"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "e5fd8ce75fd15002",
        "type": "serial in",
        "z": "41d9078ecff8c4b2",
        "name": "From Arduino",
        "serial": "f031c1d7028423f9",
        "x": 590,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": [
            [
                "9ab7a180aaf89f19"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "52445f67209363f3",
        "type": "serial out",
        "z": "41d9078ecff8c4b2",
        "name": "To Arduino",
        "serial": "f031c1d7028423f9",
        "x": 410,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "9ab7a180aaf89f19",
        "type": "ui_text",
        "z": "41d9078ecff8c4b2",
        "group": "fb4c245.8e22cd8",
        "order": 1,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "name": "",
        "label": "Get Output",
        "format": "{{msg.payload}}",
        "layout": "row-spread",
        "className": "",
        "x": 750,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "fb4c245.8e22cd8",
        "type": "ui_group",
        "name": "Test",
        "tab": "9cb34fc7.ab81b8",
        "order": 1,
        "disp": true,
        "width": "6",
        "collapse": false,
        "className": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "f031c1d7028423f9",
        "type": "serial-port",
        "serialport": "/dev/ttyACM0",
        "serialbaud": "9600",
        "databits": "8",
        "parity": "none",
        "stopbits": "1",
        "waitfor": "",
        "dtr": "none",
        "rts": "none",
        "cts": "none",
        "dsr": "none",
        "newline": "\\n",
        "bin": "false",
        "out": "char",
        "addchar": "",
        "responsetimeout": "10000"
    },
    {
        "id": "9cb34fc7.ab81b8",
        "type": "ui_tab",
        "name": "Test",
        "icon": "dashboard",
        "order": 17,
        "disabled": false,
        "hidden": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't

The `node-red-admin disable` command is for disabling types of nodes (e.g. remove them from the pallet). It is not for toggling specific nodes in a flow on/off.

You can list all the node types with the `node-red-admin list` command which outputs like this:

```
...
node-red/template      template             enabled
node-red/tls           tls-config           enabled
node-red/trigger       trigger              enabled
node-red/udp           udp in               enabled
                       udp out                     
node-red/unknown       unknown              enabled
node-red/watch         watch                enabled
node-red/websocket     websocket in         enabled
                       websocket out               
                       websocket-listener          
                       websocket-client            
node-red/XML           xml                  enabled
node-red/YAML          yaml                 enabled
```

You would then choose to say disable the `file-watch` node like this:

```
$ node-red-admin disable node-red/watch
Nodes           Types   State   
node-red/watch  watch    disabled
```

If you want to toggle nodes in a flow on/off you will need to write your own client that uses the Admin API (https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/) to download the JSON of the flow, edit the node definitions and POST the changed JSON back.